# Change main package name in python

Tags: python, package

In my project I want to change the main package name.

I've a dir structure like this:

```
hallo/sub
hallo/foo
hallo/bar
```

And I want to change the main name for example to 'goodbye':

```
goodbye/sub
goodbye/foo
goodbye/bar
```

But as result the new name is always rejected! for example if I import

`import goodbye.sub.utils as utils`

It return the error

```
ImportError: No module named sub.utils
```

And clearly the old name don't works. 
The file `__init__.py` is written in all subdirectories!

I've tried to remove all *.pyc files and cache directory, I've tried to re-clone the project in another directory, but nothing, the new name is always rejected!

I'm using python2 under *nix and I'm never moved under windows.

Some idea?

Edit:
The old name works perfectly:

```
import hallo.sub.utils as utils
```

Has always worked without any errors, the problem is the name change.

Comment: It sounds as if you have *another* module with the name `goodbye`. Add a `import goodbye; print goodbye.__file__` to your script to find out what is imported instead.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. See my [session log](http://pastebin.com/ArL9WYwP).

Comment: You have right, I've done a bit of confusion with the naming of the packages. TNX.

Answer (score 0):

For imports from the outside, check the contents of `__init__.py` for variables that can throw things off -- like `__all__`.

Also, the typical idiom is:

```
from hallo.sub import utils      #tyically this
import hallo.sub.utils as utils  #instead of this
```

I can't imagine why that would make a difference, but python occasionally has silly bugs.

For imports from within the package, you can instead use [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). Within your `hallo` package you can change this:

```
import hallo.sub as sub
import hallo.sub.utils as utils
```

to this

```
from . import sub
from .sub import utils
```

Then it doesn't matter what the outer package is called.

Comment: This is not the OP's problem. It's not that the old name is used inside the package, it's that the import of the new name fails *from outside the package*.

Comment: Ok that's a possible solution. but the global import works with 'hallo' and not with 'goodbye'.

Comment: I don't think the "python occasionally has silly bugs" is true. Often is those who use it that don't completely understand what they are doing(with e.g. relative imports/cyclic imports etc.).
Obviously there are bugs but that's unavoidable with complex softwares.